# MSSQL - SELECT on data from JOIN reference

Tags: sql-server, join

SQL Server being used to run this
I'm trying to pull information that could be variable.. Could you please check it and find the error?

```
SELECT 
  id         = t.id
  name       = c.name
  fav_flavor = ISNULL((SELECT value FROM ce WHERE key='flavor'), '')
  fav_color  = ISNULL((SELECT value FROM ce WHERE key='color'), '')
FROM
  Transaction t
  LEFT JOIN Customer ON t.customer_id=c.id
  LEFT JOIN CustomerExtra ce ON ce.id=c.id
```

Of course this is a siplified query to be used in this example, but it has the scense.

So, basically, I'm not able to use that **ce** table referenced in the JOIN statement to get random values (in this case 'flavor' and 'color') in the main query.
Is there a way to access those values without adding the condition in the last JOIN and having to duplicate that line as many times as I need values from it? or... is it the right way?

```
SELECT 
  id         = t.id,
  name       = c.name,
  fav_flavor = ce1.value,
  fav_color  = ce2.value,
  cust_other = ce3.value
FROM
  Transaction t
  LEFT JOIN CustomerExtra ce1 ON ce1.id=c.id AND ce1.key='flavor'
  LEFT JOIN CustomerExtra ce2 ON ce2.id=c.id AND ce2.key='color'
  LEFT JOIN CustomerExtra ce3 ON ce3.id=c.id AND ce3.key='other'
```

Comment: Your `CustomerExtra` table sounds like it's designed with the [EAV anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/93124) which is part of your problem. *Generally*, EAV should be avoided. In a more normalized design, you'd be able to solve this problem more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use Outer apply:

```
SELECT
...
,CE.*
FROM
...
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT
  Color = max(case when key = 'color' then value else '' end)
,flavor = max(case when key = 'flavor' then value else '' end)
FROM
CustomerExtra ce
Where
Ce.id = c.id
) CE
```

de here

Because for each customer errow you have muktiple extra key-pair values, using a  aggregate function allows you just pivot this vakues to columns.